# How to import newtype instance

Tags: haskell, ghc

I extracted persist code generating record types into a separate module (Dao) 
and I want to keep imports clean and strict so I tried to import explicitly all types and functions, I need, from Dao module. I stuck with newtype instance for Key. Key is not my type family. It is defined in persist library.

```
import Dao -- work but it is a mystery how much is imported
```

GHC (8.6.5) is looking pretty smart and even trying to help with my struggle:

```
    In module `Dao':
      `RedirectMappingRKey' is a data constructor of `Key'
    To import it use
      import Dao( Key( RedirectMappingRKey ) )
    or
      import Dao( Key(..) )
   |
52 | import Dao (openDbPool, RedirectMappingR(..), RedirectMappingRKey)
```

but both version suggested by GHC is reject by it:

```
    Module `Dao' does not export `Key(RedirectMappingRKey)'
   |
52 | import Dao (openDbPool, RedirectMappingR(..), Key(RedirectMappingRKey))
```

or

```
C:\pro\demo\haskell\servant\myproject\src\Lib.hs:52:47: error: Module `Dao' does not export `Key(..)'
   |
52 | import Dao (openDbPool, RedirectMappingR(..), Key(..))
   |                                               ^^^^^^^
```

instance definition

```
*Dao> :i RedirectMappingRKey
newtype instance persistent-2.9.2:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.Key
                   RedirectMappingR
  = RedirectMappingRKey {...}
```

I run out of ideas, probably qualified import could help me,
 but I would like to know the best solution.

Comment: Can you show your export list from `Dao`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Key is not my type family. It is defined in persist library

Then you can’t import it from `Dao`, unless `Dao` specifically lists `Key` in its export list (see https://taylor.fausak.me/2016/12/30/automatically-export-haskell-modules/). In order to use `Key`, you must add the `persistent` library as a dependency, then do `import Database.Persist.Class (Key(..))` to import it from `persistent`.